# IndexError: Dimension out of range (expected to be in range of [-2, 1], but got 3)

Tags: python, function, pytorch, transpose, ragged-tensors

I created a random function with the line below

```py
x = torch.randn(4, 3)
```

and used the transpose function as shown here

```py
torch.transpose(x, 0, 1)
```

I got the error line below. Who can assist with a solution

---

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-28494ba2cedc> in <module>()
----> 1 torch.transpose(x, 0, 3)

IndexError: Dimension out of range (expected to be in range of [-2, 1], but got 3)
```

Comment: works for me, you sure that's the problem? btw, this is the same as `x.T`

Comment: The error message indicates you transposed `axis=0` with `axis=3` (not `axis=1`). Please check your code.

Comment: Hi Ivan, I crosschecked and the error persists

Comment: Ohh, it worked finally thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to transpose x = torch.randn(4, 3), which is 2D. torch.transpose(x, 0, 1) works fine because you swap dimensions 0 and 1. But then, you try to swap dimensions 0 and 3 by doing torch.transpose(x, 0, 3) but your x does not have the 3rd dimension